# NetBeans and MinGW :'test' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, mingw, netbeans-7

I'm using NetBeans 7.4 with ported version of MinGW from [EquationSolution](http://www.equation.com).
The problem is the `make` command. Eventhough it's inside the `bin` directory of the compiler which is located in `C:\MinGW`, NetBeans doesn't recognize it and I have to manually set it.
After doing that, hitting build button causes the following message:

```
'test' is not recognized as an internal or
 external command,
 operable program or batch file.
 The syntax of the command is incorrect.
 ! was unexpected at this time.
 make: *** [.validate-impl] Error 255
```

I feel I'm missing something, what is it?

Comment: It doesn't look like a `test` utility is provided with that MinGW package.  You might need to install an `msys` package or some other set of Unix utilities to get a `test` executable.

Comment: I'm currently installing `msys` packages and so far not `test` executable

Comment: UnxUtils has it: http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/